# Group by and order with different columns

Tags: php, mysql, database

If I use group by and order by with the same column the sort works as expected. HOwever I want to group by one field and order by another. my statement is as follows

```
 WHERE item_id= '$item_id'   GROUP BY  dateofitem ORDER BY millis ASC

                $results[$i] = array( 
                        'header' =>$ROW['date'],
                        'count' => $ROW['COUNT(title)'],
                          =>explode(",",$ROW['GROUP_CONCAT(item_id)']),
```

and so forth. No matter what I do, I can't group my items and sort them

the output in one of my groupings is like so:

```
"start_time":["06:39:00","08:42:00","09:42:00","01:43:00","20:44:00"],
"start_time":["06:39:00","08:42:00","09:42:00","01:43:00","20:44:00"],"
```

if I get rid of "group by" and obviously group contat I am able to sort with no issue whatso ever.

Comment: The issue is that that you need to order the result set by some other criteria than is available in your current data. Ok, imagine that you store the result in another table then join that with whatever criteria you want to use to sort it. yes, two pass and not very efficient. pragmatic?

Comment: I actually just needed to use nicknames for each "column" using the AS operator. Strange but it worked

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this! When using GROUP BY, you cannot select other columns other than the column that you use for grouping, except you use some aggregate functions for those columns. In this case, you can use ORDER BY on the aggregated data.

Comment: do you have an example or a resource to point me to? At least I know i CANNOT do that. now. But why doesn't SQL support sorting within each object?

Comment: if you cannot select the data, how can you sort them :) You should show us your tables and what you want to do so that we can figure out how to do it easier.

Comment: Actually, you *can* do this. MySQL explicitly allows this as an [extension to `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html). It is a problematic extension because it allows for non-deterministic (i.e., unpredictable) queries, but it is a valid MySQL query. [MS SQL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) and Oracle allow you to use the `OVER()` clause to accomplish the same thing with many aggregate functions. The problem @Dnaso is having is because his query is non-deterministic.

Comment: lets pretend im a little lost be the answer.. =) how would I accomplish what I am trying to do then?